# How do I get a server.js file to pull a password from another file like config.js?

Tags: javascript, database, server, passwords, config

How do I get the server.js file to pull a const password from my config.js file?

In my server.js, I write:

```
const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host : '127.0.0.1', /*home*/
        user : 'postgres',
        password : databaseCode,
        database : 'exampleDatabase'
    }
});
```

In the config.js file, I write:

```
const databaseCode = "examplePassword";
```

I tried this above the const db:

```
const databaseCode = require('./config.js');
```

---

```
console.log('databaseCode:'+databaseCode);
```

gives me

```
databaseCode:[object Object]
```

---

I'm exporting from server.js.
The config.js is to hold a password to hide the password from git.
If I replace databaseCode with the actual password, the app works.

Comment: Are you exporting databaseCode from config.js? e.g. `module.exports = databaseCode`

Comment: module.exports = databaseCode; worked!! How do I thank you and close this out?

Answer (score -1):

```
module.exports = databaseCode
```

as stated by https://stackoverflow.com/users/7607737/aaron-kvarnlov-leverty